# PHP - PDO Transaction sequence

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my MySQL database very rarely I get duplicate rows. I'm just looking at my code and I want to check if my transaction code is causing this problem. Here is it:

```
        try
        {
            $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $con->beginTransaction();

            $sql1 = $con->prepare("query_to_update_tb1");
            $sql2 = $con->prepare("query_to_insert_tb2");

            $sql1->execute();
            $sql2->execute();

            ...

            $sql3 = $con->prepare("query_to_insert_tb1");
            $sql4 = $con->prepare("query_to_insert_tb2");

            $sql3->execute();
            $sql4->execute();

            $con->commit();

        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $con->rollback();
        }
```

Comment: It'll be hard to say if u don't provide us an example of duplicates & the queries u're using.

Comment: This is a very not useful code for others to help you...

Comment: To avoid duplication in relational databases, we use `UNIQUE` constraint so we know that there's only one such record present. You, apparently, are not doing it.

Comment: Sorry, but the queries are too interlaced with business logic. I tried to simplified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. The user was submiting multiple forms, then the duplicate fields. Nothing wrong with the code.